# Dockerfile COPY file fails

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I have a simple Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.1-apache
LABEL maintainer="rburton@agsource.com"
COPY MyAgsourceAPI /var/www/MyAgsourceAPI
COPY MyAgsourceAPI/conf/php/drivers /usr/lib/apache2/modules/
COPY MyAgSourceAPI/conf/php/apache2/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
```

Using the build command:

```
docker build -t rkevinburton/myagsourceapi .
```

The last line returns the error:

```
Step 5/5 : COPY MyAgSourceAPI/conf/php/apache2/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder231753667/MyAgSourceAPI/conf/php/apache2/php.ini: no such file or directory
```

All the other 'COPY' lines execute without error. I am not clear what this means or how my Dockerfile should change. I am taking this COPY mostly from the documentation on docker hub for php. This may be due to a read-only nature of /usr/local/etc/php. But I cannot tell from the error. Ideas?

Comment: It is saying the local `MyAgSourceAPI/conf/php/apache2/php.ini` file doesn't exist. Are you able to confirm that `file MyAgSourceAPI/conf/php/apache2/php.ini` returns something and the file is readable?

Comment: I cannot seem to get the formatting right but something like 'ls -l C:\Users\rburton\code\MyAgSourceAPI\conf\php\apache2\php.ini' from the PowerShell window gives me a 'Mode' of '-a----'.I have looked at the Windows properties for this file and it has the 'read-only' flag unchecked.

Comment: Make sure the the file `php.ini` case is all lower. Linux and containers are case sensitive when it comes to files and folders and powershell isn't

Comment: I changed the command line to 'COPY myagsourceapi/conf/php/apache2/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/' (changing the folder path in the src to lower case) but I still get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the line to

```
COPY MyAgsourceAPI/conf/php/apache2 /usr/local/etc/php/
```

Which copies the content (which is only one file) works. Though I am still not sure how to copy just a single file.

Answer (score -1):

what solved the issue for me is that I need to make sure all the files I'm about to COPY need to be in the same folder  as my Dockerfile (not in any folder above it) which is the same folder where I run the docker build command.
if I placed them outside of that folder - the COPY would fail as described.

Comment: This is not the case. Copy works with subdirectories with no issue.

Answer (score -1):

according to the documentation , COPY and ADD work only on the build directory : [ADD doccumentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add)

> The  path must be inside the context of the build; you cannot ADD ../something /something, because the first step of a docker build is to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker daemon.

So you can copy a file by "download it " to the build directory . Or you can mount a volume in the run command.

remove copy line and on the run command , try this :

```bash
docker run -v /absolute/path/MyAgsourceAPI:/var/www/MyAgsourceAPI -v /absolute/path/MyAgsourceAPI/conf/php/drivers:/usr/lib/apache2/modules/ -v /absolute/path/MyAgsourceAPI/conf/php/apache2/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini <theidoftheimage>
```

No sure that is the best way or the best practice but that's work